# Calling getUserMedia on Safari causes sound on mac os x to be silent for a second

Tags: macos, audio, safari, microphone, getusermedia

As of Safari 11, they have started supporting WebRTC apis natively.

In my web application I am using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` to get control of the microphone.

I noticed that, only in Safari, when my code calls getUserMedia, the sound on my computer gets low then comes back up to normal volume after a second.

I have tested this on another website: https://simpl.info/getusermedia/

When I loaded the website, I did not see the issue..
The site above only requests for video, but the code is very simple and not minified.  I put a breakpoint right where it calls getUserMedia and added the constraint for audio and I was able to reproduce the issue.

Has anyone else had this problem?  I am unable to find anything online describing this issue.

I am running Mac OSx El Capitan.  I know I am out of date but people have told me that this happens on Sierra as well.

Comment: I have same issue on safari 11 and safari 12. Are you able to solve this issue? If yes, please share the answer.

Comment: No it's still a problem!
I wish that Safari would put out some proper documentation on their APIs, maybe include side effects of using them as well!

Answer (score 1):

The same on High Sierra.
My guess is they try to avoid audio spikes or to go easy on the echo canceler.